# Inserting csv value into multiple rows not working in desired way with SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
Insert Into MessagingMessageReceipient
      (
       MessageId,
       ReceipientId,
       ReceipientType
      )
      SELECT
       @pEMailId,
       csv.Part,   -- each @pReceiver
       1
      FROM 
      dbo.inline_split_me(',',@pReceivers) csv
```

case 1:

if `@pReceiver` contains  -- "a," only

then above stored procedure results in inserting two rows (one with 'a' another with blank)

case 2.

while if `@pReceiver` contains -- "a" only

then above stored procedure results in inserting zero row

case 3.

it is working fine only if `@pReceiver` contains -- "a,b" type of values

How to make it working fine in all types of input

function

```
CREATE FUNCTION inline_split_me (@SplitOn char(1),@String varchar(7998))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (WITH SplitSting AS
           (SELECT
                LEFT(@String,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)-1) AS Part
                    ,RIGHT(@String,LEN(@String)-CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)) AS Remainder
                WHERE @String IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)>0
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                LEFT(Remainder,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)-1)
                    ,RIGHT(Remainder,LEN(Remainder)-CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder))
                FROM SplitSting
                WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)>0
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                Remainder,null
                FROM SplitSting
                WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)=0
           )
           SELECT Part FROM SplitSting
       )
```

I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: achieved case one also by replacing last line of fucntion with  SELECT Part FROM SplitSting where Part IS NOT NULL AND PART <> ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Alter FUNCTION inline_split_me (@SplitOn char(1),@String varchar(7998))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (WITH SplitSting AS
           (SELECT
                LEFT(@String,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)-1) AS Part
                    ,RIGHT(@String,LEN(@String)-CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)) AS Remainder
                WHERE @String IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)>0
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                LEFT(Remainder,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)-1)
                    ,RIGHT(Remainder,LEN(Remainder)-CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder))
                FROM SplitSting
                WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)>0
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                Remainder,null
                FROM SplitSting
                WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)=0
           )
           SELECT Part FROM SplitSting where LEN(Rtrim(Coalesce(Part,''))) >0
       )
```